# toString Not Following Correct Format

Tags: java, queue, push, tostring

I am having trouble when I call my `toString` method and my code isn't following the correct format like it should, this is how I've been trying to call it.

```
public static void loadQueue(Queue<String> queue, String str) {

    String elementArray[] = str.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++){
        queue.push(elementArray[i]);
        queue.toString();
    }

}
```

Here is the toString that I want to format it to:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    String str = "[ ";

    if ( !isEmpty() ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length - 1; i++){
            str += queue[i] + ", ";
        }

        str += queue[queue.length - 1] + " ";
    }

    str += "]";

    return str;
```

Is there a better way to be calling this so that it prints out the correct out put?

Correct format should be [ a, b, c, d ] but all I'm getting is [ abcd ].

Edit, added toString method

Comment: your code has no output, and what would "correct" output be?

Comment: this doesn't seem to use "your" toString method. It will call the String class toString method, which just returns itself.

Comment: You are calling `toString()` on a `String`. This will always return the same `String`, which makes no sense. Please tell us exactly what you want and why your code doesn't achieve that

Comment: getting closer. Now take the queue.toString and put it after the loop and do something with the result.

Comment: `StringJoiner` is your friend

Comment: I've tried moving the queue.toString to the outside of the loop but it still didn't work.  Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the values between commas in the `str` as the values to push onto the `queue` then you don't need to call toString().

Does this work for you?

```
public static void loadQueue(Queue<String> queue, String str) {
    if (null == queue) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected non-null queue");
    if (null == str) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected non-null str");

    String elementArray[] = str.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++){
        queue.push(elementArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: or just `queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(elementArray))`

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell which class your toString override is on, but it wouldn't be on string or queue.

`Queue.toString` will probably not be what you want. Is there some reason you want to override toString rather than just have a method by another name?

Technique #1
Put all the methods in your existing class

```
public String queueToString(Queue<String> queue) {
    String str = "[ ";

    if ( !isEmpty() ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length - 1; i++){
            str += queue[i] + ", ";
        }

        str += queue[queue.length - 1] + " ";
    }
    str += "]";

    return str;
}

...

public static void loadQueue(Queue<String> queue, String str) {

    String elementArray[] = str.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++){
      queue.push(elementArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println( queueToString(queue) );
```

}

Technique #2
Create a custom class for your queue and modify the behavior.

```
public class MyStringQueue extends Queue<String> 
{
    @Override
    /* override the toString method here */
}

...

/* in your class, create an use a MyStringQueue instead of Queue<String> */
public static void loadQueue(MyStringQueue  queue, String str) {

    String elementArray[] = str.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++){
      queue.push(elementArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println( queue.toString() );
```

}